Obtaining homology groups with $\mathbb{Z}_2$ coefficients from those with integer coefficients
I am trying to understand if one can expresses (simplicial) homology groups $H_n(K,\mathbb{Z}_2)$ of simplicial complex $K$ from the knowledge of $H_n(K,\mathbb{Z})$ alone. It seems the answer follows from the universal coefficient theorem, but I am unfortunately not familiar with the concept of the Tor functor used there, so I am trying to avoid it.
My thinking goes along the following lines.
First, if there is a $\mathbb{Z}$ component in the free part of $H_n(K,\mathbb{Z})$, then this is generated by an $n$-cycle $c_n$, $\partial c_n = 0$, which is not itself a boundary, i.e. $c_n \neq \partial d_{n+1}$, and also no integer ($k$) multiple of $c_n$ is a boudnary, i.e., $\forall k \in \mathbb{Z}^+: c_n \neq \partial d_{n+1}$. However, with $\mathbb{Z}_2$ coefficients, $2 c_n = 0 = \partial (0)$, where by the latter zero I mean the trivial element of the $(n+1)$-chain group. Therefore, every $\mathbb{Z}$ contribution to $H_n(K,\mathbb{Z})$ gives a corresponding $\mathbb{Z}_2$ contribution to $H_n(K,\mathbb{Z}_2)$.
Next, let the torsion part of $H_n(K,\mathbb{Z})$ contain a $\mathbb{Z}_m$ contribution with $m$ odd. This contribution is generated by an $n$-cycle $c_n$, $\partial c_n = 0$, such that $m$ is the smallest positive integer such that $m c_n = \partial d_{n+1}$. Now, if we take the coefficients modulo two, we obtain $c_n = \partial d_{n+1}$ (because $m = 1$ (mod 2) for $m$ odd), which means that $c_{n}$ is no longer a non-trivial cycle. Therefore, the $\mathbb{Z}_m$ contribution to $H_n(K,\mathbb{Z})$ with $m$ odd is lost in $H_n(K,\mathbb{Z}_2)$.
Similarly, if $H_n(K,\mathbb{Z})$ contain a $\mathbb{Z}_m$ contribution with $m$ even, then modulo two one finds that $c_{n}$ remains non-trivial in $H_n(K,\mathbb{Z}_2)$ while $2 c_n = 0$ is trivial. Therefore, every $\mathbb{Z}_m$ contribution to $H_n(K,\mathbb{Z})$ with $m$ even gives a $\mathbb{Z}_2$ contribution to $H_n(K,\mathbb{Z}_2)$.
However, this is not the whole story. It could be that an entirely new contribution appears in $H_n(K,\mathbb{Z}_2)$ which had no counterpart in $H_n(K,\mathbb{Z})$. These contributions seems to originate from the torsion part of $H_{n-1}(K,\mathbb{Z})$. For example, for the real-projective plane, $H_2(\mathbb{R}P^2,\mathbb{Z}) = 0$, in particular because (due to non-orientability) the entirety of the surface of $\mathbb{R}  P^2$ has a boundary. However, this boundary contains all $1$-simplices with even multiplicity; therefore, the surface of $\mathbb{R} P^2$ actually has no boundary if we consider the homology theory with $\mathbb{Z}_2$ coefficients. As a consequence, $H_2(\mathbb{R}P^2,\mathbb{Z}_2) = \mathbb{Z}_2$, which is in some way inherited from $H_1(\mathbb{R}P^2,\mathbb{Z}) = \mathbb{Z}_2$.
Based on all these observations, I am wondering whether the following statement could be universally true. That we can write the homology group $H_n(K,\mathbb{Z}_2)$ as a product of two components: (1) For the free part in $H_n(K,\mathbb{Z})$, replace each contribution $\mathbb{Z}$ by $\mathbb{Z}_2$; and (2) for the torsion part of both $H_n(K,\mathbb{Z})$ and $H_{n-1}(K,\mathbb{Z})$, add to $H_n(K,\mathbb{Z}_2)$ a $\mathbb{Z}_2$ contribution for each $\mathbb{Z}_m$ with $m$ even (and drop $\mathbb{Z}_m$ with $m$ odd).
Could this be true? If not, is there another simple formula which can be written without the use of the Tor functor?
I am sorry that my explanation is a bit long, I am sure things become much more compact with the proper choice of mathematic concepts (such as the Tor which is intentionally avoided).

The other alternative is that you could learn the Tor functor. It's not that hard. I would say that your post amounts to an attempt at a long winded version of the universal coefficients theorem combined with the standard formula for evaluating the Tor functor when applied to a finitely generated abelian group... but you might get in trouble if the homology groups are not finitely generated...
